# Is WSDL 2.0 supported in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, wsdl

I am trying to generate a web service client for WSDL 2.0 web service, but, eclipse (**Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1) Build id: 20140925-1800**) does not seems to recognize wsdl 2.0 and expects a wsdl 1.0 syntax.

As per eclipse installation details , **It also has web tools platform version 3.6.1 support in it**.

Is there any way to enable eclipse to handle wsdl 2.0 ?

**Does eclipse supports wsdl 2.0 ?**

Thanks & Regards
Mandeep